# AngularJS memory leak with ng-switch? Can someone solve this?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I've built a custom routing method for angularjs and I use this to control ng-switch within my app in order to create multi level deep linking.

http://plnkr.co/edit/beAm3WRomMafKzx1SoSZ?p=preview

What i can't figure out is why the memory keep going up when you switch between the social and contacts tab under share. Also if you look in baterang ( the angularjs plugin for chrome ) why when you switch off of contacts tab does the scope not become smaller?  Contacts controller has been destroyed but baterang shows that the contacts are still in scope.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is memory leak when ngRepeat and ngSwitch directive are involved and Batarang plugin is enabled. Here is ticket about it: https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/62